# Can I simplify the way my javascript function is called?

Tags: jquery

I have the following that I execute inline on a number of screens:

```
tinyMCE.init({
    // General options
    mode : "specific_textareas",
    editor_selector : "mceEditor",
    theme: "advanced",
    plugins: "autolink,lists,spellchecker,pagebreak,style,layer,table,save,advhr,advimage,advlink,emotions,iespell,inlinepopups,insertdatetime,preview,media,searchreplace,print,contextmenu,paste,directionality,fullscreen,noneditable,visualchars,nonbreaking,xhtmlxtras,template",

    // Theme options
    theme_advanced_buttons1: "save,newdocument,|,bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,|,styleselect,formatselect,fontselect,fontsizeselect",
    theme_advanced_buttons2: "cut,copy,paste,pastetext,pasteword,|,search,replace,|,bullist,numlist,|,outdent,indent,blockquote,|,undo,redo,|,link,unlink,anchor,image,cleanup,help,code,|,insertdate,inserttime,preview,|,forecolor,backcolor",
    theme_advanced_buttons3: "tablecontrols,|,hr,removeformat,visualaid,|,sub,sup,|,charmap,emotions,iespell,media,advhr,|,print,|,ltr,rtl,|,fullscreen",
    theme_advanced_buttons4: "insertlayer,moveforward,movebackward,absolute,|,styleprops,spellchecker,|,cite,abbr,acronym,del,ins,attribs,|,visualchars,nonbreaking,template,blockquote,pagebreak,|,insertfile,insertimage",
    theme_advanced_toolbar_location: "top",
    theme_advanced_toolbar_align: "left",
    theme_advanced_statusbar_location: "bottom",
    theme_advanced_resizing: true,

    // Skin options
    skin: "o2k7",
    skin_variant: "silver",

    // Example content CSS (should be your site CSS)
    content_css: "css/example.css",

    // Drop lists for link/image/media/template dialogs
    template_external_list_url: "js/template_list.js",
    external_link_list_url: "js/link_list.js",
    external_image_list_url: "js/image_list.js",
    media_external_list_url: "js/media_list.js",

    // Replace values for the template plugin
    template_replace_values: {
        username: "Some User",
        staffid: "991234"
    }
});
```

I would like to move this into a file and then call it. Is there a simple way that I can do this?

Comment: Belongs on: codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similiar to [Xander](https://stackoverflow.com/users/88932/xander)'s answer, but I would only store the options object globally.

```
window.tinyMCEOptions = {
    // General options
    mode : "specific_textareas",
    /* Your other options here.
     * Store in your favorite .js file and link your page to it.
     */
}
```

Then call `tinyMCE.init` like:

```
tinyMCE.init(window.tinyMCEOptions);
```

The advantage of this is that it allows you to change options easily:

```
window.tinyMCEOptions.content_css: 'css/different.css'
tinyMCE.init(window.tinyMCEOptions);
```

Answer (score 1):

In a `base.js`:

```
window.pageinit = function(){

    tinyMCE.init({

        /* ... your initialization code ... */

    });
}
```

In a page that references `base.js`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    pageinit();

</script>
```

Comment: Thanks. I never saw "window." used. What does it do?

Comment: window is the global object in the browser. This is where the `document` object and other global objects are defined...